# Comparing the dates in a custom Adapter class (Null Pointer Exception)?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-adapter, android-date

I have a custom adapter. I try to compare the current date and the entered date in it.
But ı got null pointer exception. I can't figure out why is the reason of this exception.
My LogCat is below and the line with the problem is that "((ViewGroup) todoView).getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(0x01060018);
" Can someone help me?

my adapter class;

```
public class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> { 

    private int resource; 
    Context context;
    ArrayList<ToDoItem> todoItem;

    public ToDoItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ToDoItem> objects) { 

        super(context, resource, objects); // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
        this.resource = resource;
        this.context = context;
        this.todoItem = objects;
    } 

    @Override 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        LinearLayout todoView; 
        ToDoItem todo = getItem(position); 
        String priorityString = todo.getPriority(); 
        String taskString = todo.getTask(); 
        String dateString = todo.getDeadline(); 
        String statusString = todo.getStatus();

        if (convertView == null) 
        { 
            todoView = new LinearLayout(getContext()); 
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE; 
            LayoutInflater li; 
            li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater); 
            li.inflate(resource, todoView, true); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            todoView = (LinearLayout) convertView; 

            int len = todoItem.size();

            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                String deadline = todoItem.get(i).getDeadline();
                String status = todoItem.get(i).getStatus();
                String currentDate =  findCurrentDate();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                java.util.Date data=null;
                try {
                    data = sdf.parse(deadline);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                java.util.Date current =null;
                try {
                    current = sdf.parse(currentDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    System.out.println(data);

                }
                if(status.equals("DONE"))
                {
                    ((ViewGroup) todoView).getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
                    System.out.println(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(data);
                    if(data.compareTo(current)>0 || data.compareTo(current)==0){
                        ((ViewGroup) todoView).getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(0x01060018);
                    }else if(data.compareTo(current)<0){
                        ((ViewGroup) todoView).getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(0x01060016);
                    }
                }
            }
        } 

        TextView priorityView = (TextView) todoView.findViewById(R.id.itemPriority); 
        TextView taskView = (TextView) todoView.findViewById(R.id.itemTask); 
        TextView dateView = (TextView) todoView.findViewById(R.id.itemDeadline); 
        TextView statusView = (TextView) todoView.findViewById(R.id.itemStatus);

        priorityView.setText(priorityString); 
        taskView.setText(taskString); 
        dateView.setText(dateString); 
        statusView.setText(statusString);
        return todoView; 

    } 

    private String findCurrentDate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        String date = day+"-"+(month+1)+"-"+year;
        return date;
          }
}
```

LogCat

```
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at com.example.enhancedtodolistapplication.ToDoItemAdapter.getView(ToDoItemAdapter.java:107)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2161)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5008)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-16 17:32:12.357: E/AndroidRuntime(3148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

outputs (for two different items' date)

```
11-16 18:44:30.687: I/System.out(4087): variable deadline 15-10-2012
11-16 18:44:30.697: I/System.out(4087): variable currentDate 16-11-2013
11-16 18:44:30.717: I/System.out(4087): variable data Mon Oct 15 00:00:00 EDT 2012
11-16 18:44:30.727: I/System.out(4087): variable current Sat Nov 16 00:00:00 EST 2013
11-16 18:44:30.757: I/System.out(4087): variable deadline 17-12-2014
11-16 18:44:30.757: I/System.out(4087): variable currentDate 16-11-2013
11-16 18:44:30.767: I/System.out(4087): variable data Wed Dec 17 00:00:00 EST 2014
11-16 18:44:30.777: I/System.out(4087): variable current Sat Nov 16 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Comment: Well either data is null or current is null, not much we can do their for you, find out why thats the case!

Comment: If the date parsing for `data` or `current` fails, you are only printing the stack trace, and in this case you can get the NullPointerException. Check for `deadline` and `currentDate` values to see what is wrong.

Comment: Indeed. Print and show us the values of: deadline, currentDate, data (after you initialise it), and current. By that time though, you should be able to find which one is causing the issue...

Comment: I edited my question for outputs

Comment: What line is causing the fault?  I'm going to guess - see my answer below.

Comment: The line is causing the fault i writed to my question.   "((ViewGroup) todoView).getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(0x01060018); "

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't properly initialized your new layout for the (convertView == null) case.

You do

```
 li.inflate(resource, todoView, true);
```

Please realize that the result from "inflate" is the inflated view.  The middle param will become the parent - usually this is some sort of ViewGroup or a ListView.  In any case, it's the "parent" param of getView().

Then, later on, you try to find child views of todoView.  However it's empty so those calls will return null.  Subsequent references will fault.

Here's a simpler way to do the inflate:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
 todoView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate (resource, parent, false);
```

Comment: I don't think inflate where the problem is